# Starting DesktopCouch or CouchDb on Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, couchdb, desktopcouch

I have installed DesktopCouch on my Lubuntu 12.10 using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install desktopcouch
```

Installation was ok, but when I try to start it with command `couchdb`, I get the following error:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,
[normal,["/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,
{error,{error,enoent}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,   
[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,56}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,
[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0
[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

*Line-breaks added to the JSON for better readability*

I have checked file `/etc/couchdb/default.ini` and I have created folder for data mentioned there (it was `/var/lib/couchdb/1.2.0/`) and assigned the 777 access rights to it. But it doesn't help.

I also tried `sudo couchdb`, but the result is the same.

File, mentioned in the error (`erl_crash.dump`) has 16k lines, makes no sense to me

I checked and another CouchDB is not running:

```
$ couchdb -s
Apache CouchDB is not running.
```

Running out of ideas... Do you know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't install or use desktopcouch. It is no longer maintained or supported. See the [EOL announcement for desktopcouch](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-November/003474.html). Also, couchdb will soon be completely disabled on the Ubuntu One servers, as [announced recently](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2013/02/04/notification-about-notes/). It's not stated in that announcement, but notes sync was the last remaining service backed by couchdb on the server. Once it's down, there will be no more couch access on Ubuntu One (syncing with which was the sole reason for desktopcouch). The desktopcouch package has been removed from the archive completely in 13.04.

Comment: I'm not talking about Ubuntu One, but about Lubuntu, installed on my laptop. I simply need to get _any_ kind of CouchDB instance running on my laptop. Is there any chance?

Comment: CouchDB is a system service. `sudo service couchdb start` should start it, but you may be missing a required package for that if you install desktopcouch as a way of getting couchdb.

Comment: ok, I removed desktopcouch, I installed regular couchdb. Now the command `couchdb` gives still the same error, but `sudo service couchdb start` works and it really starts couchdb. Thanks...